# HTML5Boilerplate with Yii Framework

Tags: php, html, build-process, yii, boilerplate

Has anyone managed to integrate HTML5 Boilerplate in the YII PHP Framework (specifically the folder structure and build process)?

Comment: Why not do configuration with HTML5 Boilerplate?

Comment: @Zuo - Can you please explain?

Comment: @user1151271 With my limited knowledge of boilerplate, I think you can just do configuration on the folder path (js/css/images) of boilerplate project to use the build tool feature of boilerplate. For the index.html, simply use it with the main layout file of yii project.

Answer (score 5):

Boilerplate recommends using the @import when adding styles to the head.

```
<style>@import(/example.css);</style>
```

Yii uses the ClientScript model to add

```
<link type="text/css" src="/example.css" />
```

Use the Yii::app()->clientScript Model to register the file. Yii allows you to register script files as needed, per controller or per view. Therefor your http requests can be minimal. I would suggest registering the required scripts/css in the main layout and add other scripts as they are needed with the

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile();
```

Yii is based on the MVC model. The V is for view. The view foldes contain the html elements your model and controller will adjust based on data types. Inside the view folder Yii uses the layout folder to define layouts.

```
$this->layout = 'main';
```

That line will look for:

```
Protected -> views -> layout -> main.php
```

The layout folder should contain main, _htmlHead, _header and _footer. The renderPartial will be used for render the different layout parts. It's like a php include for HTML. The second param of $this->render or $this->renderPartial is used to pass data to the view. For example nav data:

```
$this->renderPartial('_footer', array('nav'=>array('/link/'=>'Link Name')));
```

In the _htmlHead register the needed elements using the Yii::app()->clientScript. If you want to use a different version of jQuery then use the ScriptMap model, don't register jQuery twice. Yii's coreScript, validation and paging are based on jQuery.

```
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->registerCssFile('/css/base.css'); 
$cs->registerScriptFile('/js/base.js', CClientScript::POS_END);
/* Load Script at END of DOM tree: CClientScript::POS_END */
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript

In the past I've used the config.php file in Yii to set an assetsLocaion parameter. If I move my assets it won't break the site.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->param->assetsLocation.'/js/example.js');
```

The basic layout of the boilerplate will be defined in the layout/main.php. Check out the theme documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming

Layout File Might look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php $this->renderPartial('//layouts/_Htmlhead); ?>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('//layouts/_header); ?>
    <div id="main" role="main">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    <?php $this->renderPartial('//layouts/_footer); ?>
  </div> 
  <?php $this->renderPartial('//layouts/_footerScripts); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note the FooterScripts are optional. Yii::app()->clientScript has a param for script placement (i.e. postHead, postContent, postBody)

Comment: I just have a couple of follow up questions:

1) HTML5 Boilerplate recommends that all CSS files be merges into their base style.css. When using BP together with YII, would you recommend sticking with this practice? The same goes for jQuery plugins and other external js files.

2) Can you please elaborate on this comment: "Add the HTML Header, page header tag and page footer tag into their own view under layout. The layout folder should contain main, _htmlHead, _header, _footer. In the _htmlHead register the needed elements using the Yii::app()->clientScript."?

Thanks again!

Comment: @AgileAce I've updated the layout section. Hope that helps. The more scripts and css files you use, the more http request your website must make. Keeping the http request to a minimal is very important. People developed compression and sprites to lower the number of request. The beauty of Yii's clientScript is have the ability to load scripts and css files as needed. You don't have to load all your CSS files in the main layout. If one page needs special javascript, you can load the needed information on the fly. If you really need to keep http request lower, check out an extension for Yii.

Answer (score 3):

Check my Yii BoilerPlate and Bootstrap Integration

https://github.com/drumaddict/YiiApp

Comment: I created a new repo with an updated version                            https://github.com/drumaddict/YiiApp

Answer (score 1):

A simple Yii HTML5 Boilerplate theme is available at https://github.com/neam/yii-html5-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

There is a very detailed Wiki article by Antonio Ramirez titled:

**YiiBoilerplate - Setup a professional project structure in seconds**
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/374/yiiboilerplate-setup-a-professional-project-structure-in-seconds/

Sources for this setup:
https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate

Answer (score 0):

What about 
https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate 
I think they Uses HTML5Bilerplate